Power Automate date conversion error when using planner/outlook template
I am trying to create a flow that will add/create an event in Outlook Calendar when a task is assigned in Planner. I have found a template that seems to accomplish this however, when trying to test I receive the following error that the date input isn't valid because of the timezone:

Below are the parameters and template.

The following are the template create functions for start and due date time respectively
coalesce(triggerBody()?['startDateTime'],utcNow())
coalesce(triggerBody()?['dueDateTime'],utcNow())
I ran this test manually by assigning myself a task in Planner. I was expecting an event to be created in my outlook calendar instead I received the above error message.
I've done some research and have asked on the Microsoft Power Automate forum and haven't been able to find much that will help with this issue I'm experiencing. However, I am relatively new to Power Automate and don't know exactly what I am looking for. I would greatly appreciate any help or direction in this matter.

Is the startDateTime and dueDateTime being passed into the trigger body or is it failing over to utcNow()?

From what I understand it is being passed into the trigger body and Outlook doesn't like having the UTC attached but I'm honestly not sure. The functions were apart of the flow template in Power Automate and weren't something I adjusted as I feared breaking something further.
